# Unity 3d FFT spectrum with procedural audio

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, fft

I'm generating some procedural audio by using the OnAudioFilterRead method on Unity 3d, and it's working beause I can hear the synthesized sound from the speaker.

When I'm trying to get the spectrum of the synthesized sound (in the same script) with

```
void Update()
{
    float[] data = new float[2048];
    audioSource.GetSpectrumData(data, 0, FFTWindow.BlackmanHarris);
}
```

It always fills `data` array with 0 (no exception thrown). Is there any way to get the real spectrum of the synthesized audio?

Comment: Maybe the window size is too big? What documentation on function says?

Comment: Documentation says the maximum size is 8196. I'm also using that function to get another spectrum (from microphone) with the same code and in that case the function is working.

Comment: Is there any function to check state of audioSource? If there is, what does it return? Maybe audioSource object have flushed or empty buffer? Maybe it's in invalid state?

Comment: You say you synthesize sound, are 100% sure that there's something in the buffer of audioSource when you ask it for FFT?

Comment: I can't inspect the buffer directly, but there's a meter in Unity UI that shows when some audio is coming out from that script and it's moving while GetSpetrumData is being called

Comment: You should definitely look into differences of working with synthesized sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been fixed in version 5.2